# Inverse search stopped working in Kile (Live Preview)

Tags: 18.04, latex, kile

I have been using Inverse Search with Kile in Ubuntu 18.04 since I freshly installed my OS in 2018.

I've been using the Live Preview while writing my texts in LaTeX. In the Document Viewer window, when left-clicking a line while pressing the Shift key, Kile used to move the cursor to the right position inside my *.tex file*.

I didn't change any configuration in Kile, but that inverse search stopped working in the last week.

I have already tried `dpkg-reconfigure kile`, `apt install --reinstall kile`, and `apt purge kile; apt install kile`, but none of the procedures fixed the problem.

Can anyone help me to discover what is the cause and how to fix it, please?